# undefined local variable or method in my Rails app, but recognised when app first loads

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get replaceWith/html jQuery functions working in my Rails app.

My review_main.html.erb has this DOM structure:

```
<div class="left_window"></div>
<div class="right_window"></div>
```

My edit.html.erb has this:

```
<div class="edit_review_form">
  <div class="cancel-edit" id="<%= @review.id %>"></div>
    <div class="inputs"></div>
</div>
```

review_main.html.erb is called like this, when my app loads:

```
<!-- I need the 'breadcrumb div' to be outside of review_main, because it will help with my jQuery html/replaceWith  -->
<div class="breadcrumb" id="review_<%= review.id %>">
  <%= render 'reviews/review_main', :review => review %>
</div>
```

So the loaded DOM looks like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb" id="review_<%= review.id %>">
<div class="left_window"></div>
<div class="right_window"></div>
</div>
```

I call an edit.js.erb from my review_main.html.erb like this:

```
    <div class = "right_window">
    <%= link_to I18n.t('user.review.edit.edit'), edit_review_path(review), :remote => true, :class => "edit_review_link" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and in the edit.js.erb file I have:

```
$('#review_<%=@review.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit') %>")
$('#review_<%=@review.id %>').animate({height:'250px'}, 300);
```

so everything works great up to here. The DOM structure changes to:

```
<div class="breadcrumb" id="review_<%= review.id %>">
<div class="edit_review_form">
  <div class="cancel-edit" id="<%= @review.id %>"></div>
    <div class="inputs"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is changing the DOM back to:

```
<div class="breadcrumb" id="review_<%= review.id %>">
<div class="left_window"></div>
<div class="right_window"></div>
</div>
```

In my _edit.html.erb I have a 'Cancel' link, which is supposed to load once again _review_main.html.erb.

Cancel is called like:

```
<%= link_to I18n.t('user.review.edit.cancel'), review_path(@review), :remote => true %>
```

In a show.js.erb file I have:

```
$('#review_<%=@review.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'review_main' ) %>")
```

But the new info isn't rendered. Nothing in review_main is recognised. In Console I can see:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/reviews/51 500 (Internal Server Error) 

and

NameError in Reviews#show

Showing /home/mycompaq/myapp/app/views/reviews/_review_main.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined local variable or method `review' for #<#<Class:0x7f2fe74a6c08>:0x7f2fe76ca048>
Extracted source (around line #8):
```

I'm not getting any errors when review_main.html.erb loads the first time round, so just confused why it's happening now. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Change `edit_review_path(review)` to  `edit_review_path(@review || review)` (because in your show action, you have the `@review` object but not the `review` object).

Comment: Now I get a 'routing error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>#<Review id: nil, user_id: nil, author_id: nil...etc...Sorry, thrown in at deep end with this project.My reviews_controller.rb has 'def edit/
@review = Review.find(params[:id])/end. Routes.rb has: resources /:reviews do/ member do/ get :repost, :reject/end/ end. Any tips on what to do I'd be grateful.

Comment: Got it sorted with a review_block